# How to insert a static Card to the timelime?

Tags: google-glass

how is it possible to insert a static card to the timeline with Glass Development Kit Preview:19 via the gdk? I need to push a card on the right side of the timeline while been able to associate a share action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the Authentication API and then call Mirror from your GDK app via Account info to insert the card.  Based on the documentation the static card feature in the GDK have gone away and you have to use mirror.

Comment: Thank you John, I was trying to avoid using the mirror api as I havent really looked into it and it looks like extra work that I am avoiding...